# How can I suppress Excel's password prompt in Perl?

Tags: perl, excel, passwords

Please tell me a solution to suppress passsword prompting of an excel file.

```
    use Win32::OLE;

      my $xlApp = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application');

      $xlApp->{Visible} = 0;

      $xlApp->{DisplayAlerts} = 0;

      # Open excel file.
      my $xlBook = $xlApp->Workbooks->Open("C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Desktop\\testfile.xls");
      my $Sheet1 = $xlBook->Worksheets(1);

        my $row = 1;
        my $col = 1;

       $Sheet1->Cells($row,$col)->{'Value'} = 5;

        if (Win32::OLE->LastError) 
        {
                print "File protected";
        }

      $xlBook ->Close();

  undef $xlBook;
```

Comment: You may be better off using <a href="http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel">Spreadsheet::ParseExcel</a> and <a href="http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel">Spreadsheet::WriteExcel</a> than messing around starting up a copy of Excel and mucking around with OLE. It'd be a lot more portable too.

Answer (score 5):

If you know the passwords, you can supply them in the password and/or writerespassword arguments of the open command. Excel will not prompt for the passwords if they are supplied this way.

If you don't know the passwords but want to prevent the dialog box from appearing, you can supply dummy passwords in these parameters ("ThisIsNotAPassword", for instance). I have not found this in the documentation, but tested it in Excel 2003:

- If the Excel file does not have passwords, it is opened.
- If it does have passwords (other than those supplied), it will not ask the user for a password, but fail with an error you can detect.

Comment: So is the following correct ?

my $xlBook = $xlApp->Workbooks->Open("D:\\Perl\\bin\\search tool\\test.xls","ThisIsNotAPassword");

Comment: Sorry, that won't work. The open method signature is Open(FileName, UpdateLinks, ReadOnly, Format, Password, WriteResPassword, /* others deleted */), you can find this in the help of Excel vba ide. You need to specify parameters by name or supply eveything up to and including writerespassword.

Comment: You mean like this :


Open("D:\\Perl\\bin\\search tool\\test.xls",Password ="ThisIsNotAPassword");

Comment: I'm not sure whether Perl allows this. If so, I do mean that:-) You also need to supply a WiteResPassword, because Excel allows two different passwords, for reading and for editing.

Comment: The vba syntax would be open(Filename:=("D:\\Perl\\bin\\search tool\\test.xls",Password:="ThisIsNotAPassword",WriteResPassword:="ThisIsNotAPassword")

Comment: I don't know Perl, but am hoping that
my $xlBook = $xlApp->Workbooks->Open("D:\\Perl\\bin\\search tool\\test.xls",0,0,1,"ThisIsNotAPassword","ThisIsNotAPassword"); will work. I have selected parameter values for UpdateLinks, ReadOnly and Format that I hope will not hurt.

Comment: Perl uses a hashref to pass named parameters.  Try Open("D:\\Perl\\bin\\search tool\\test.xls", {Password=>"ThisIsNotAPassword",WriteResPassword=>"ThisIsNotAPassword"})

Comment: Could you indicate what goes wrong. Do you get an error, does Excel start but you still get a dialog box? What does happen?

Comment: If you dont use WriteResPassword then it works.

The new problem is that the Excel files get opened in the background(invisible).We come to know about this when we open the Excel Software.
I tried to destroy the object but still it opens in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You may convert the following vb code to perl and give a try,
Please note that this code is for vbproject, similary you can check for the worksheets, cells, or entire sheet, the same way.

' returns TRUE if the VB project in the active document is protected
' Please not

```
Function ProtectedVBProject(ByVal wb As Workbook) As Boolean

Dim VBC As Integer

  VBC = -1

  On Error Resume Next

  VBC = wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Count

  On Error GoTo 0

  If VBC = -1 Then

    ProtectedVBProject = True

  Else

    ProtectedVBProject = False

  End If

End Function
```

Example:

```
If ProtectedVBProject(ActiveWorkbook) Then Exit Sub
```

For Worksheet

```
If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure=True  Then Exit Sub
```

For active work book windows

```
If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectWindows= True Then Exit sub
```

and so on..

Or You can open excel sheet with password

The Open method for the Workbook 
object, takes 12 arguments.  To open a workbook with password protection, you would need to write the following code:

```
 Workbooks.Open "Book1.xls", , , ,"pswd"
```

You can also check with perl the same with empty arguments. I am not sure how to give...

Comment: How to convert the code to Perl ?

Is there any help document ?

Comment: May be $xlBook->Worksheets(1)->Protectstructure . And also I am doing the same in VB

Answer (score 0):

Working off of lakshmanaraj's idea, and unknown's response:

```
use Win32::OLE;

sub is_protected_vb_project { 
    my $work_book = shift;
    eval { 
        my $count = $work_book->{VBProject}{VBComponents}{Count};
    };
    Carp::carp $@ if $@;
    return $@ ? 1 : 0;
}

my $work_book = Win32::OLE->GetObject( 'd:/some/path/somewhere.xls' );
printf "is_protected_vb_project( \$work_book )=%s\n"
     , is_protected_vb_project( $work_book )
     ;
```