# Is there a way in Perl to check if a document is password protected

Tags: perl, winapi

Before opening any word or excel document, I would like to know in advance if the document is password protected, and if so, I want to skip it.

I am using Win32::OLE to open the file.

Comment: Check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568924/how-can-i-suppress-excels-password-prompt-in-perl

Answer (score 0):

A way is to try to open the document using a dummy password.

Following is a method I tried.

```
my $Word =  Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application');

if(!$Word){
    # Word can't be opened, exit or return false
}

my $Doc;
eval{$Doc = $Word->Documents->Open("Path to your doc",undef,undef,undef,"thisIsPassword");};
if($@){
    # Document opening failed, exit or return false   
}
if(!$Doc){
    # File doesn't exists, exit or return false   
}

my $var = Win32::OLE->LastError() ;
if($var){
    # File may be password protected, exit or return false
}
unless ($Doc eq '') {
    # Do whatever...
}
```